# Android animation stops to display at the end of Layout

Tags: android, animation, layout, space

I'm trying to do a TweenAnimation (Scale and translate) with two ImageViews (top and bottom). Each ImageView (and some other stuff) is in a RelativeLayout and the RelativeLayouts are in a LinearLayout. The images moves to the left top corner of the display. The Animation works fine, but at the end of the (Relative) Layout the animation disappears (in the mid of the display).
Is there any way to give the animation more (all) space then only the parent View? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the parent view to not clip it's children and allow them to draw outside it's bounds. In your XML, add this:

```
android:clipChildren="false"
```